# How can I export CSV with multiple tables?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter to extract tables from a PDF file. The PDF in question has multiple tables, but when I try to convert into CSV, the only table that shows up is the last one.

```
import tabula

tables = tabula.read_pdf('myfile.pdf', pages = 'all')

for table in tables:
    display(df)

table.to_csv('myfile.csv')
```

I don't want multiple CSV files, I want a single CSV file that contains all of the tables on the PDF. Is that possible?

Comment: This is answered in the FAQ in the documentation: https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#i-want-to-extract-multiple-tables-from-a-document

Comment: Use `multiple_tables = True` option

Comment: It still only shows the last table as CSV.

Comment: You should combine all the dataframes into a single df, then write that to the CSV.